# How to add append product category in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I use below code to add one product category to a product which is added database;

```
wp_set_object_terms( $the_post_id, 528, 'product_cat' );
```

and it appends the relevant product category to that post (I can see the category name on products page). But when I tried to do it with and submit form, it only creates and appends as number like 528 (I see the 528 on product page instead of category name);

```
$kategori = $_POST['kategori'];
wp_set_object_terms( $the_post_id, $kategori, 'product_cat' );
```

How can I add these all categories if it should be in parent categories also with a submit form?

Comment: try type casting your value i.e (int)$kategori

Comment: @kurt Thank you, it worked for a single category. How can I add multiple categories that are parent of each other?

Comment: I added an official answer below. If you find it helpful please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type cast your value to prevent it being used as a string.

```
$kategori = $_POST['kategori'];
wp_set_object_terms( $the_post_id, (int)$kategori, 'product_cat' );
```

As to parent categories im not sure although I think this post has what you need.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99681/how-to-set-hierarchical-terms-to-a-post-using-wp-set-object-terms